# how to make the footer to stick exactly at the bottom of the page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm using ASP.net Master page. I've a footer in my page. When content of my page is less, the footer is coming in the middle of the page.

What do i need to do. please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more link for the same think

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a CSS sticky footer: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/. Using a little bit of CSS (see http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css) the footer will stick to the bottom as much as possible:

1. If the page's content is higher than 1 viewport: nothing happens.
2. If the page's content is not higher than 1 viewport: the footer creates whitespaces and prefers to stick to the bottom.

Er... there should be more rules...